# Showing $\int\sin(x) dx=-\cos(x)+C$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I show this without using fundamental theorem of calculus? It is not a homework, but it suddenly occurred to me that I can't show it. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the power rule? If so:
$$\sin x= x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+\cdots$$
$$\int\sin x\, dx= \int x-\int x^3/3!+\int x^5/5!-\int x^7/7!+\int\cdots$$
$$\int\sin x\, dx= x^2/2+c_1- x^4/(3+1)3!+c_2+ x^6/(5+1)5!+c_3- x^8/(7+1)7!+c_4+\cdots$$
$$\int\sin x\, dx= x^2/2- x^4/4!+ x^6/6!- x^8/8!+\cdots+C$$
$$\int\sin x\, dx-1=-1 +x^2/2- x^4/4!+ x^6/6!- x^8/8!+\cdots+C$$
$$\int\sin x\, dx-1=-(1-x^2/2+ x^4/4!- x^6/6!+ x^8/8!-\cdots)+C$$
$$\int\sin x\, dx -1=-\cos x+C$$
$$\int\sin x \, dx=-\cos x+C_1$$
Where $C=\sum_{i} c_i$, and in step 8, $C+1=C_1$
In step 1 I used the power series of sine and in step 7 I used the power series of cosine.

Comment: This is marvelous. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a formula for an antiderivative, not a definite integral, so you show it by differentiating the right side and seeing that you get the left: this does **not** use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  If the question was to show that, say, $\int_0^x \sin(t)\; dt = 1 - \cos(x)$, that could be done using
a Riemann sum
$$ \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \sin(j t/n) $$ 
and [Lagrange's trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange.27s_trigonometric_identities) for the sum of sines.